# Saving bash output in Dockerfile as ENV var

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am setting up a random password to be used on the initial login within my `Dockerfile`. I have tried

```
ENV PASSWORD=RUN date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32
```

Which does not work because Docker commands are in separate containers. I also tried

```
RUN export PASSWORD= date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32
```

Which has also failed.

I have also tried to redirect my output to a file, which also fails, the file stays empty and no error is given.

```
RUN date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 > test.txt
```

How can I save the output from this command as an ENV var to be used in my Docker container?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

The following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN echo "bd" > /test.txt
```

when run has the `test.txt` file present:

```sh
docker build . -t test:latest
docker run -it --rm test:latest
> cat /test.txt
> 'bd'
```

You could change your command to write a file in a `source`able manner (`RUN echo "my_env_var=$(echo 'stuff')" > /test.txt`) and then have your entrypoint include `. /test.txt`

Comment: I tried the simple example provided above. There is still nothing being output to the file and no errors reported